# FastAPI NameError: name 'Request' is not defined

Tags: python, fastapi, uvicorn

I'm loosely following a turorial on building a full stack trading app and trying to run this script with FastAPI and uvicorn. I really can't find my mistake and also don't really know what I'm doing so any help is really apprecciated.

The code:

```
import sqlite3, config
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.get("/")
def index(request: Request):
    connection = sqlite3.connect(config.DB_FILE)
    connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT id, symbol, name FROM stock order by symbol
    """)

    rows = cursor.fetchall()

    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request, "stocks": rows})

@app.get("/stock/{symbol}")
def index(request: Request, symbol):
    connection = sqlite3.connect(config.DB_FILE)
    connection.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute("""
        SELECT id, symbol, name FROM stock WHERE symbol = ?
    """, (symbol,))

    row = cursor.fetchall()

    return templates.TemplateResponse("stock_detail.html", {"request": request, "stock": row})
```

The error

```
line 9, in <module>
    def index(request: Request):
NameError: name 'Request' is not defined
```

Thanks so much for taking the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the Request class.

Please, change de line 2 to: `from fastapi import FastAPI, Request`

Answer (score 0):

You need to import `Request`. Replaced you first line:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
```

Comment: Glad it is resolved and welcome to Stack Overflow, @throavvay! Since this is your first question, please consider voting up or accepting the answer. This helps other users who encounter the same issue to easily find a solution that fixed the same problem. Here's more information for why: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers